# Any vector in $V$ is a linear combination of the vectors $\{v_i\}$ in a basis of $V$ .

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Any vector in $V$ is a linear combination of the vectors $\{v_i\}$ in a basis of $V$ . this means that $\forall u \in V$ we have :$u=u_1v_1+u_2v_2+\cdots + u_nv_n$

I am reading upon a fact about vector and I have a question. It is true that a vector space can be written as a linear combination of basis vectors, but why do we have to add a span in front to indicate that vector space is a span of basis vectors, unlike a vector of a vector space in which why can just write as a sum of those basis vectors? (My question maybe ambiguous, let me know)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a basis $B = \{b_1,\cdots,b_n\}$ of an n-dimensional vector space V over the field $\mathbb{K}$, we can express V as $span(B)$, that is $$V = span(B) = \{k_1b_1 + \cdots +k_nb_n|k_1,\cdots,k_n \in \mathbb{K}\} $$  This means that the entire set of vectors in V can be obtained by exhausting all possible linear combinations of the basis vectors $\{b_1,\cdots,b_n\}$, or that is is possible to construct V from just the basis vectors, by considering all possible linear combinations, with the scalars coming from $\mathbb{K}$.